# libtool error during compilation

Tags: c++, libtool

I am cross compiling my source package for Intel environment with `skerlet` gcc compiler

I am getting a `libtool` error:

```
../libtool: line 6412: cd: =/usr/lib: No such file or directory
libtool: link: warning: cannot determine absolute directory name of `=/usr/lib'
/usr/bin/grep: =/usr/lib/liblber.la: No such file or directory
```

How did the additional "=" get added ?

Comment: Try to run the command that causes manually with `set -x` before that.

Comment: I suspect a typo during compilation or installation: it seems that "/usr" became "=/usr"

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a typo in some sort of makefile or an invalid bash variable assignment:

`$BLAH=/usr/lib`

prints
`bash: =/usr/lib: No such file or directory`

on my machine.

Fastest way of finding the problem may be searching the sources of your package like this:

`grep -Hnir "=/usr/lib"`

This will display filenames and and line numbers of any matches. If that fails to find anything try searching in the toolchain installation directory.

When you get matches try tracing it back to any input you have provided during installation.

Comment: Thanks JarekD for your inputs.

Comment: I removed all the .la files which was referrring to "=/usr/lib"from the toolchain /usr/lib/ and re compile ..it worked. I refered only .so files